# How to share data between cordova apps using cordova-plugin-file? (Android, IOS)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

I have two apps that they both should write/read some txt files. The most logical way is doing this using [cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/). However, i could not find directly a resource explaining it explicitly.

The good news is that there is a URL called shared directory `cordova.file.sharedDirectory` which is exactly what I need but it is only for BlackBerry 10. (While I need them for `android` and `IOS`)

**For android:**

from the docs of the [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file);

> If the SD Card was mounted, or if a large internal storage partition
>   was available (such as on Nexus devices,) then the persistent files
>   would be stored in the root of that space. This meant that all Cordova
>   apps could see all of the files available on the card.
>
> If the SD card was not available, then previous versions would store
>   data under /data/data/, which isolates apps from each
>   other, but may still cause data to be shared between users.

So, as far as I understand, if there is SD card, data can be easily shared (which we cannot assume that all users have SD card). Otherwise data of apps are isolated but still can be shared. But the question is how? Knowing the path of app is already enough or is there some restrictions to reach data of other app?

**For IOS:**

I'm absolutely not sure which URL to use to share data between apps.

Comment: I'm not sure I get this. You can not possibly mean that you want to share files on two different devices with the same file system? It doesn't matter if it's Android or iOS - how would you share a file on one device with another device without sync to a server somewhere? How would that work? Sounds like magic

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter I think it's two apps within one device.

Comment: How was your progress with this one, Asqan?

Comment: my colleague created somehow a txt file on global SD card, which was used by both apps but this is really not advisable. Currently, we don't share info between apps

Comment: @Asqan ah yes, there's an issue of security. Thanks! Going back to searching again.

Answer (score 0):

Just use cordova file transfer plugin to upload to server with app1 and then get file with app2